# Xmx and gc log max heap size difference?

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm, java

Need to know why there is difference between **Xmx jvm startup parameter** and **gc log Max Heap size**

1563.749: [GC 1563.749: [ParNew: 226929K->11859K(235968K), 0.0605702 secs] 735329K->523980K(**1808832K**), 0.0616580 secs]

**java version - 1.5.0_06**
**Also Xms == Xmx**

Comment: -Xmx is 1792Mb i dont know why there is difference

Answer (score 0):

-Xmx parameter specifies only the *maximum* heap size. JVM is free to choose any size lower than that and it could dynamically change. You could also specify initial heap size via -Xms and if you set it equal to -Xmx presumably heap size shouldn't change much.

**UPDATE:**
Now when you mentioned that you also have -Xms == -Xmx my answer above no longer applies. Looking at your numbers again it appears that they're actually pretty close:

```
1,792M = 1,835,008K
```

So looks like the reported discrepancy is just about 27M or just slightly over 1%. Why is it concerning you?

Comment: That doesn't follow from your question

Comment: I was going through calculation of old and young generation occupancy and promotion rate and observed that 1) Xms == Xmx, 2) Max Heap Capacity in gc log 3) jvm startup max/min heap size is different than gc log max heap size. So for calculation which max heap size shall i use?